# Electrical Outlet - Red and black wire to L1 T1

Tags: electrical, wiring, thermostat, receptacle

Background: I removed an in line wall heater thermostat from a 120v outlet, and want to ensure I reconnect the wires accurately.

Question: A [google search hit](http://www.doityourself.com/forum/electrical-ac-dc/432669-replacing-4-wire-220v-wall-heater-thermostat.html#b) insists the wire marked in red is running from the the panel, and if tested should be active if circuit is on, and should connect to the "L1", the other wire black and not labeled runs to the heater and connected to the "T1". Is this accruate? Is testing the connection with circuit on necessary? Out of curiosity, do the characters stand for anything?

[image]

Comment: Can you post a photo looking into the back of the box?

Comment: outlet or thermostat product box?

Comment: The outlet box, although a photo of the thermostat's backside might be helpful too

Comment: The outlet box seems like it's screwed in from the back and doesn't seem worth the effort to remove for this project.

Comment: Finally found a [manual](http://www.homedepot.com/catalog/pdfImages/50/50241949-25f7-428f-87cb-914b95bdea8b.pdf), step 3 has a diagram that provides detail that T1 connects to heater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

L is for line or supply. T is for load. Basically L is power in and T is power out.

If you are trying to find which wire is coming from the panel, yes the power must be on. The one from the panel will show voltage. Which I assume will be the one marked with red tape.